# Rstudio does not turn to dark theme for right panes on Mac; Tried all fonts and themes

Tags: r, macos, fonts, themes, rstudio

No matter what selection, I just can’t seem to turn the right  panes in R studio to dark theme: [image]

[image]

Comment: In the Appearance tab, what is the theme currently selected? It should be either Modern or Sky.

Comment: I don’t see either of those themes. I am using a really old (2013) Mac Pro with R studio 1.0.15 and R version 4.0

Comment: Update RStudio to v1.4 https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download

Comment: That worked!!  very strange that the earlier version was only showing half the panes in dark mode. Thanks @Phil